# Mockito limitations

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

In the bottom of [this](https://www.jayway.com/2012/02/25/mockito-and-dependency-injection/) page, one can read:

***Fields may not be declared as final or static (but private fields are supported).***

what does it mean? Is it telling that within a test-class I can not annotate with @Mock fields that are static or final?

Comment: What about it don't you understand? Do you not know what the final and static keywords do in the Java language?

Comment: Of course I know, just I didn't get what shouldn't be final or static in Mockito.

Comment: It means that fields in the *tested* class (the one used in an `@InjectMocks` field in the test class) should not be final or static, if they are to be injected with `@Mock` instances.

Answer (score 1):

We write unit tests for dynamic behavior of the code. Mockito doesn't support testing constants fields, JMock will do.

Comment: are you telling me that within a test-class I can not annotate with @Mock fields that are static or final because they wouldn't be mockable?